# How to insert Java Date and Timestamp value to mysql databas in spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a register page to add flight details, while trying to insert Date and Time in mysql database, but i am getting error rejected value [22-02-2020]; and rejected value [12:00]; , could some one guide me how to resolve this.

My Flight Model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FLIGHT")
public class Flight {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int ID;
    private String flightnumber;
    @Column(name="operatingairlines")
    private String operatingAirlines;
    @Column(name="departurecity")
    private String departureCity;
    @Column(name="arrivalcity")
    private String arivalCity;
    @Column(name="departuredate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    @Column(name="departuretime")
    private Timestamp estimatedTravelTime;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getFlightnumber() {
        return flightnumber;
    }

    public void setFlightnumber(String flightnumber) {
        this.flightnumber = flightnumber;
    }

    public String getOperatingAirlines() {
        return operatingAirlines;
    }

    public void setOperatingAirlines(String operatingAirlines) {
        this.operatingAirlines = operatingAirlines;
    }

    public String getDepartureCity() {
        return departureCity;
    }

    public void setDepartureCity(String departureCity) {
        this.departureCity = departureCity;
    }

    public String getArivalCity() {
        return arivalCity;
    }

    public void setArivalCity(String arivalCity) {
        this.arivalCity = arivalCity;
    }

    public Date getDateOfDeparture() {
        return dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public void setDateOfDeparture(Date dateOfDeparture) {
        this.dateOfDeparture = dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public Timestamp getEstimatedTravelTime() {
        return estimatedTravelTime;
    }

    public void setEstimatedTravelTime(Timestamp estimatedTravelTime) {
        this.estimatedTravelTime = estimatedTravelTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flight [ID=" + ID + ", flightnumber=" + flightnumber + ", operatingAirlines=" + operatingAirlines
                + ", departureCity=" + departureCity + ", arivalCity=" + arivalCity + ", dateOfDeparture="
                + dateOfDeparture + ", estimatedTravelTime=" + estimatedTravelTime + "]";
    }

}
```

Login Controller

package com.tcdc.FlightReservation.controller;

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;


    @GetMapping("/showform")
    public String showRegistration() {
        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registerUser")
    public String SaveRegister(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        //user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        System.out.println(user);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showlogin")
    public String showLogin() {
        //userRepository.
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/LoginProcess")
    public String LoginProcess(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        System.out.println(user);
        if((user.getPassword().equals(password))&&(user.getRole().contentEquals("0"))) {
            return "findFlights";
        }
        else if((user.getPassword().equals(password))&&(user.getRole().contentEquals("1"))) {
            return "AddFlight";
        }
        else {
        return "login";
        }

    }

}
```

FlightController

```
@Controller
public class FlightController {

    @Autowired
    FlightServices flightServices;

    @Autowired
    FlightRepository flightRepository;

    @PostMapping("/flightResult")
    public String findFlights(@RequestParam("from") String from,@RequestParam("to") String to,@RequestParam("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy") Date departureDate, Model model) {

        //flightRepository.findFlight(from,to,departureDate);
        System.out.println(from+" "+to+" "+departureDate);
        List<Flight> flist = flightServices.searchFlight(from,to,departureDate);
        model.addAttribute("flightdetails", flist);
        System.out.println(flist);
        return "FlightResults";
    }


    @PostMapping("/SaveFlight")
    public String SaveFlight(@ModelAttribute("flight") Flight flight) {

        flight.getDateOfDeparture();

                    //flightRepository.save(flight);


        return "FlightResults";
    }


}
```

Error

```
2020-02-19 20:02:35.580  WARN 3048 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'flight' on field 'dateOfDeparture': rejected value [22-02-2020]; codes [typeMismatch.flight.dateOfDeparture,typeMismatch.dateOfDeparture,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [flight.dateOfDeparture,dateOfDeparture]; arguments []; default message [dateOfDeparture]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'dateOfDeparture'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '22-02-2020'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [22-02-2020]]
Field error in object 'flight' on field 'estimatedTravelTime': rejected value [12:00]; codes [typeMismatch.flight.estimatedTravelTime,typeMismatch.estimatedTravelTime,typeMismatch.java.sql.Timestamp,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [flight.estimatedTravelTime,estimatedTravelTime]; arguments []; default message [estimatedTravelTime]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Timestamp' for property 'estimatedTravelTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.sql.Timestamp] for value '12:00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]]]
```

Mysql Table details

```
ID                    int(11)   NO  PRI 
flightnumber        varchar(50) NO      
operatingairlines   varchar(50) NO      
departurecity       varchar(50) NO      
arrivalcity         varchar(50) NO      
departuredate        date       NO      
departuretime        timestamp  NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. Just use `Date` with following annotation.

```
@Column(name="departuretime")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date estimatedTravelTime;
```

Comment: Getting error : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: com.tcdc.FlightReservation.Models.Flight.estimatedTravelTime

Comment: @VyTcdc you have to use java.util.Date

Comment: Change timestamp to  java.util.Date but agan type mismatch error as above.